# Error in Arduino-ROS connection

Tags: arduino, rosserial, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to all!

A few months ago, I connected Arduino to ROS fuerte using rosserial without problems. However, now I'm trying to reproduce it in ROS groovy and I always get the same error.

I am working with Ubuntu 12.04, ROS Groovy, Arduino 1.0.5, rosserial-groovy-devel and both Arduino Uno and Arduino Mega.

I do these commands:

Window 1:

sudo ./Arduino/arduino

Open Hello World example.

Select Controller Arduino Uno/Mega.

Select Serial Port /dev/ttyACM0.

Load code.

Window 2:

roscore

Window 3:

sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0

rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0

And I get this error:

[INFO] [WallTime: 1394533587.406466] ROS Serial Python Node

[INFO] [WallTime: 1394533587.419060] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1394533590.332723] Creation of publisher failed: unpack requires a string argument of length 4

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1394533591.328157] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138526/error-in-arduino-ros-connection/) by [Jota](https://answers.ros.org/users/13121/jota/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try removing and remaking your ros_lib.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved!

There was a problem in the installation of ros_lib due to Arduino sketchbook permissions.

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [Jota](https://answers.ros.org/users/13121/jota/) with karma: 13 on 2014-03-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1